# Compare 2 Objects Value and key

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects:

```js
Obj1 = {
  0: "AS1",
  1: "AS2",
  2: "AS3"
}


Obj2 = {
  AS1: "Hani"
  AS2: "Joe"
}
```

I want to compare the value of `Obj1` with the key of `Obj2` and print `Obj2` values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: what means *comparing*?

Comment: @NinaScholz i have table,  i want to print all values from Obj2 depends on the Keys in Obj1

Comment: This is like a VLookup in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let ob1 = {0: "AS1", 1: "AS2", 2: "AS3" }

let ob2 = {AS1: "Hani", AS2: "Joe" }

let ob1Vals = Object.values(ob1)
let ob2Keys = Object.keys(ob2)

console.log(ob1Vals, ob2Keys)

ob2Keys.forEach(e => {
    if(ob1Vals.includes(e)) {
        console.log(ob2[e])
    }
})
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array with the values of `obj1` and iterate for the keys of `obj2`.

```js
var obj1 = { 0: "AS1", 1: "AS2", 2: "AS3" },
    obj2 = { AS1: "Hani", AS2: "Joe" },
    result = Object.assign([], obj1).map(k => k in obj2 ? obj2[k] : null);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good use of `Object.assign` +1

Comment: how to return all values in Obj1 with there names from Obj2 in (return) please, in the example above i should return 3 values Hani,Joe,Null

Comment: what means return? do you want an array of values with `null` for `undefined` properties?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is it that you want to achieve but You can access the values you need like this:

`let Obj1values = Object.values(Obj1);`

`console.log(Obj1values)`

`let Obj2Keys = Object.keys(Obj2);`

`console.log(Obj2Keys)`

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the equivalent to Excel's VLOOKUP function (sans the exact match option).

Search the source object by the value of the current `User` and return the `Name` value. Since this is a scalar value, no field/index is needed.

```js
const lookup = (value, source, field) => {
  return ((match) => {
    return match && field ? match[field] : match || null;
  })(source[value]);
}

let Users = {
  0: "AS1",
  1: "AS2",
  2: "AS3"
}

let Names = {
  AS1: "Hani",
  AS2: "Joe"
}

console.log(Object.keys(Users).map(id => {
  return lookup(Users[id], Names);
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```